# PHP preg_match url

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a problem with preg_match in PHP.

I have URLs:

```
http://mysite.com/file/w867/2612512232
http://mysite.com/file/c3233/2123255464
etc.
```

I need URLs:

```
http://mysite.com/file/2612512232
http://mysite.com/file/2123255464
```

I must remove:

```
w867/
c3233/
etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need to use preg_match. parse_url() can do the job.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Just make sure to concatenate it all against without the part you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

you could try a pattern like this:

`"/(.*)\/([^/])*\/(.*)/"`

and then with str_replace you can: `$string = str_replace('/'.$matches[2], '', $string);`

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace("|file/\w+/|", "file/", $url);
```

This will search for 1st pattern between "/" symbols just after "file/" part.